# Printing elements of an array in C

Tags: c, array

I'm trying to print the elements of an array in a fashion that resembles thism where `SIZE` is a constant:

---

```
     0        10        20        30        40        50        60        70        80        90
     1        11        21        31        41        51        61        71        81        91
     2        12        22        32        42        52        62        72        82        92
     3        13        23        33        43        53        63        73        83        93
     4        14        24        34        44        54        64        74        84        94
     5        15        25        35        45        55        65        75        85        95
     6        16        26        36        46        56        66        76        86        96
     7        17        27        37        47        57        67        77        87        97
     8        18        28        38        48        58        68        78        88        98
     9        19        29        39        49        59        69        79        89        99
```

---

I have succeeded using this code:

```
void array_print(int *ptr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i=i+10) {
        printf("%10d", ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i=i+10) {
        printf("%10d", ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 2; i < SIZE; i=i+10) {
        printf("%10d", ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 3; i < SIZE; i=i+10) {
        printf("%10d", ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 4; i < SIZE; i=i+10) {
        printf("%10d", ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 5; i < SIZE; i=i+10) {
        printf("%10d", ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 6; i < SIZE; i=i+10) {
        printf("%10d", ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 7; i < SIZE; i=i+10) {
        printf("%10d", ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 8; i < SIZE; i=i+10) {
        printf("%10d", ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 9; i <= SIZE; i=i+10) {
        printf("%10d", ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

---

**Is there a better way to code this output?**

Comment: How about wrapping  the 4-line fragments in a loop?

Comment: Post definition of `SIZE`.  Could be constant or variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to add a `j` loop.

```
void array_print(const int *ptr) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    for (int i = j; i < SIZE; i=i+10) {
      printf("%10d", ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

---

Also look to a wider than `"%10d"` to cope with `"1234567890"` running together as well as 11 character `"-1234567890"`.  Perhaps `" %11d"`?

Better code would pass in `int columns, int rows, int size` than hard code them.

Answer (score 0):

If you can drop the original type, the best way might be to change the array type to a 2D array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array (size_t rows, size_t cols, int array[rows][cols])
{
  for(size_t r=0; r<rows; r++)
  {
    for(size_t c=0; c<cols; c++)  
    {
      printf("%4d", array[r][c]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

int main (void)
{
  int array[10][10];
  for(size_t i=0; i<10; i++)
  {
    for(size_t j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
      array[i][j] = i+10*j;
    }
  }
  print_array(10, 10, array);
}
```